# Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0

Tags: java, jsf, jpa

I have a form from my entity (weatherstation) .
I also have a field called "bezeichnung" (description). When i enter a string and i press the  search button (for searching) i always get an Exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out
>   of range: 0

In my database is one object with the bezeichnung "Traunstein"

Entity (with getter and setter):

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="findbybez", query="select w from Weterstation w where w.bezeichnung like :bez")
public class Weterstation implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    @Length(min=3, max=20, message="Min.->3 Max->20")
    private String bezeichnung;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @Pattern(regexp="[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" , message="PLZ ist falsch")
    private String plz;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @Length(min=3, max=20, message="Min.->3 Max->20")
    @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Z][a-z]*", message="Der Ort muss einen Anfangsbuchstaben machen")
    private String ort;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @TempValid(message="Min -40°C, Max 40°C")
    private double temp;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

Facade Methode:

```
@Override
    public Weterstation findbyBezeichnung(String name) {
      List e =  em.createNamedQuery("findbybez").setParameter("bez", name).getResultList();
      Weterstation w = new Weterstation();
      if(e.get(0)!=null)
      {
          w = (Weterstation)e.get(0);
      }
        return w;
    }
```

View:

```
<f:view>
                <h:form>
                    <h1><h:outputText value="Create/Edit"/></h1>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Id:" for="id" />
                        <h:inputText id="id" value="#{wettercontroller.station.id}" title="Id" disabled="true"/>
                        <h:message for="id"></h:message>
                        <h:outputLabel value="Bezeichnung:" for="bezeichnung" />
                        <h:inputText id="bezeichnung" value="#{wettercontroller.station.bezeichnung}" title="Bezeichnung" required="true" requiredMessage="The Bezeichnung field is required."/>
                        <h:message for="bezeichnung"></h:message>
                        <h:outputLabel value="Ort:" for="ort" />
                        <h:inputText id="ort" value="#{wettercontroller.station.ort}" title="Ort" required="true" requiredMessage="The Ort field is required."/>
                        <h:message for="ort"></h:message>
                        <h:outputLabel value="Plz:" for="plz" />
                        <h:inputText id="plz" value="#{wettercontroller.station.plz}" title="Plz" required="true" requiredMessage="The Plz field is required."/>
                        <h:message for="plz"></h:message>
                        <h:outputLabel value="Temp:" for="temp" />
                        <h:inputText id="temp" value="#{wettercontroller.station.temp}" title="Temp" required="true" requiredMessage="The Temp field is required."/>
                        <h:message for="temp" ></h:message>

                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:commandButton value="Create" action="#{wettercontroller.createWetter()}"></h:commandButton>
                    <h:commandButton value="SearchBez" action="#{wettercontroller.searchbez()}" immediate="true" ></h:commandButton>
                </h:form>
            </f:view>
```

Controller:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Wettercontroller implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    WeterstationFacadeLocal wetterfacade;

    private Weterstation station;

    private long id;





    /** Creates a new instance of Wettercontroller */
    public Wettercontroller() {
        station = new Weterstation();
    }
        public void searchbez()
    {
        station = wetterfacade.findbyBezeichnung(station.getBezeichnung());
    }
```

In the debugg-mode i see in the `searchbez()` that the "bezeichnung" is null.
I have to use the `immediate="true"` that the other elements will not be parsed
Please Help

Comment: if(e.get(0)!=null)
if you dont have any result you check the first elemnt (and you dont have first element) that's why you have indexoutofboundsException, and your named query mabey is wrong: try .setParameter("bez", "%" +name + "%")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bug is in your facade method.

```
List e =  em.createNamedQuery("findbybez").setParameter("bez", name).getResultList();
Weterstation w = new Weterstation();

if (e.get(0) != null) {               // <--- Here
    w = (Weterstation) e.get(0);
}

return w;
```

If the list is *empty*, then there can **impossibly** be an item at index `0`. You need to check it differently.

E.g.

```
if (!e.isEmpty()) {
    w = (Weterstation) e.get(0);
}
```

or

```
if (e.size() == 1) {
    w = (Weterstation) e.get(0);
}
```

Back to the concrete functional requirement, setting `immediate="true"` on the command button will cause all other input fields which do not have this attribute set to be **completely skipped** during apply request values, validations and update model values phases. They will end up as `null` during invoke action phase. As you seem to actually need the value of the `bezeichnung` input field to perform the action, you'd need to add `immediate="true"` to that input field as well.

```html
<h:inputText id="bezeichnung" ... immediate="true" />
```

Or, since you're already on JSF 2.x, I'd suggest to have a look at `<f:ajax>` to execute and render the form partially. E.g.

```html
<h:commandButton value="SearchBez">
    <f:ajax execute="@this bezeichnung" listener="#{wettercontroller.searchbez}" render="@form" />
</h:commandButton>
```